# How to Post a List of Users to an ASP.Core POST Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

want to post a List of User with details like Firstname, Lastname, email...
to an ASP.Core POST Action method. What is the best way to do this?

I've coded an HTML form with a jquery function to give the user feedback that a user was added to a list. But I have no idea except to put hidden inputs via jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/uvoqedjh/4/

```
 <form asp-action="Create"> 
<div class="form-group col">
 <label class="col control-label" for="vorname">Vorname</label>
 <div class="col">
   <input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" class="form-control input-md" required="">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col">
 <label class="col control-label" for="nachname">Nachname</label>
 <div class="col">
   <input id="nachname" name="nachname" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" class="form-control input-md" required="">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</form> <button id="addAnsp" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<div id="ansprechpartnerliste"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is *far* too broad, Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow the guidance there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post a user data collection to the POST Action method , you could refer to the following example :

**Model**

```
public class User 
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**CreateAthlete**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Clients.User 

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <table id="tblAthletes" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:150px">First Name</th>
                        <th style="width:150px">Last Name</th>
                        <th style="width:150px">Email</th>
                        <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="item-list">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" class="items" name="[0].FirstName" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" asp-for="LastName" class="items" name="[0].LastName" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" asp-for="Email" class="items" name="[0].Email" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" asp-for="Description" class="items" name="[0].Description" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var i = ($(".items").length) / 4;
        var n = '<tr>' + '<td><input type="text" class="items" name="[' + i + '].FirstName" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="items" name="[' + i + '].LastName" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="items" name="[' + i + '].Email" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="items" name="[' + i + '].Description" /></td>' +'</tr>';

        $("#item-list").append(n);

    });
  </script>
}
```

**Post Action method**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAthlete(List<Athlete> model)
 {
       //the logic to save data
        _context.AddRange(model);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateAthlete));
 }
```